# How to get the selected value from a group select in Blade?

Tags: laravel, input, laravel-blade, route-parameters

Is there a way one can access the value of a group select in order to use it as a parameter in a route?

This is the html element:

```
<div class="flex justify-center mt-5">
    <div class="form-control" >
        <div class="input-group">
        <select class="select select-bordered" name="search">
            <option disabled selected>Select</option>
            <option>Visits</option>
            <option>Visitors</option>
        </select>
        <a class="btn" href="">Search</a>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the route:

```
Route::get('/search/{search}', [SearchController::class, 'show_resource'])
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->name('search_resource');
```

What I am trying to do without success is to pass the selected value to the href attribute of the link, something like this:

```
<a class="btn" href="{{ search('search_resource', 'search' => $inputValue)}}">Search</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax and jquery you can do something like this:

```
function get_search(){
    var search= $("select[name='search']").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"{{route('/search/')}} + search",
        type:'GET',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
           $('#your_div').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have managed it with vanilla JS, but I was actually wondering if there's a way to handle this in Blade without using JS.

Comment: Not in core blade, but there are option in livewire